# Issue with Masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, masonry

I got this example with Masonry which works fine, but there is a strange issue though: When only green and yellow buttons are selected, it does not lay them out in two colums, but only in one... Is there a reason for this behaviour, can it be adjusted perhaps..?

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOXddW?editors=1010

```
$('.main__container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: '.item'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an empty div "grid-sizer" in masonry container

```
 columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
```

https://codepen.io/adi88/pen/oPKNWJ

Comment: great, thanks! could you explain why does this work?

Comment: When you are using percentage width for items you must add additional div that tells what is column size but that div cannot be used as itemSelector

Comment: [https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth)